# Sigma algebra of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I need to prove that $\sigma(X+Y)$ is contained in $\sigma(X,Y)=\sigma(\sigma(X) \cup \sigma(Y))$. I have read some answers using measure theory arguments, but I would like to prove it using probability theory arguments like in this way:

Let $F \in \sigma(X+Y)$. Then $\exists B \in β : (X+Y)^{-1}(B) = F$. Then...

And proceed in this way until reaching the required statement. ($\beta$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over the real numbers).

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Since $X+Y$ is $\sigma(X,Y)$ measurable, for example, by Doob's lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma; which is very useful in conditional expectation), we obtain that $\sigma(X+Y)$ is contained in $\sigma(X,Y)$